# Grouping in regular expression with python

Tags: python, regex

I have pandas series which looks like:

```
m = pd.Series(['expected != is --> found missing lices ## expected: 2.25 || is: 4.5 || expected: 3 || is: 2 ##','expected != is --> found missing lices ## expected: 3.35 || is: 5.5 || expected: 3 || is: 3 ##',
'expected != is --> found missing lices ## expected: 2.25 || is: 4.5 || expected: 3 || is: 2 ##'])
```

what I would like to do is replacing each elements of this series with:

```
'expected != is --> found missing lices'
```

I use:

```
m = m.replace('expected != is --> found missing lices ## expected: {[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?} || is: {[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?} || expected: {[0-9]\d*} || is: {[0-9]\d*} ##','expected != is --> found missing lices')
```

However, I do not get the correct result. I am new to using regular expression, I would be glad if someone can explain which part is defined wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
m = m.replace(r'expected != is --> found missing lices ## expected: \d+(?:\.\d+)? \|\| is: [0-9]\d*(\.\d+)? \|\| expected: \d+ \|\| is: \d+ ##', 'expected != is --> found missing lices', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fqW7mc/1)

Note:

- `{...}` is not a grouping construct in regexps, you need `(...)` to group and capture, or `(?:...)` to just group patterns, but in your case, you just do not need it
- The `|` char is special and needs escaping
- `[0-9]\d*` is basically `\d+`, one or more digits.